# Select query with left outer join returns too many results from primary table

Tags: sql

Ok here's the select statement

```
SELECT dbo.tbl_inspectors.user_firstname, 
       dbo.tbl_inspectors.user_lastname, 
       dbo.tbl_inspectors.user_loc, 
       dbo.tbl_appraisals.appPartA, 
       dbo.tbl_appraisals.appPartB, 
       dbo.tbl_appraisals.appAppraised, 
       dbo.tbl_appraisals.appFinalized,
       dbo.tbl_appraisals.appDate,
       dbo.tbl_inspectors.appProcStart, 
       dbo.tbl_inspectors.appDue, 
       dbo.tbl_inspectors.inspAdhocStaff, 
       dbo.tbl_inspectors.access_id, 
       dbo.tbl_appraisals.appraiseID, dbo.tbl_inspectors.user_id
FROM   dbo.tbl_inspectors 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       dbo.tbl_appraisals ON dbo.tbl_inspectors.user_id = bo.tbl_appraisals.inspectID
```

If there are multiple results against the tbl_inspectors.user_id in the tbl_appraisals table then I get more than one result for each inspector, I just want it to pull the most recent match from tbl_appraisals against the tbl_inspectors user_id, how can I achieve this simply?

PS tbl_appraisals.appDate is the field that determines the most recent result from tbl_appraisals

Comment: what column that determines the recent row?

Comment: tbl_appraisals.appDate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the engine is not MySQL...

This is a "TOP 1 per group" problem

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
    SELECT I.user_firstname, 
           I.user_lastname, 
           I.user_loc, 
           A.appPartA, 
           A.appPartB, 
           A.appAppraised, 
           A.appFinalized,
           A.appDate,
           I.appProcStart, 
           I.appDue, 
           I.inspAdhocStaff, 
           I.access_id, 
           A.appraiseID,
           I.USER_ID,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY I.user_id ORDER BY COALESCE(A.appDate, '19000101') DESC) AS rn
    FROM   dbo.tbl_inspectors I
           LEFT OUTER JOIN
           dbo.tbl_appraisals A ON I.user_id = A.inspectID
    ) X
WHERE
    X.rn = 1
```

Comment: Engine is MS-SQL, returns error :

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
Incorrect syntax near '.'.

Comment: Fixed missing comma. Which is in your question too... after appDate in the SELECT clause

Comment: Nice one, thanks gbn, on a side note I am reaching the limits of my sumwhat limited knowledge, I understand the basics, but want to get a better understanding of joins, sub-query's and the more advanced functions, can you recommend any good tutorial sources or reading material?, thanks again m8